# Is it possible to register Windows 8 enterprise evaluation

Tags: windows, windows-8, installation

officially* MS doesnt support registering W8 Enterprise evaluation, but I wonder is there might hack to do it. 
By this I mean legally purchasing Win8 Pro DVD and using that key to register installed Win8 enterprise evaluation OS.

*

> Q: What happens after the evaluation period expires?
>
> A: If you wish to continue to use Windows 8 Enterprise after the
>   evaluation period, you will be required to purchase and perform a
>   clean installation of Windows 8, including drivers and applications.

Comment: License keys are specific to each Windows version, you can't exchange  them. A hack will go against the Windows 8 Enterprise licensing agreement, as Microsoft is crystal clear in the Q&A you provide (from here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/jj552442.aspx) about what to do when the 90-day evaluation period expires.

Comment: There is no way to legally do want you want to do.  The Windows 8 Enterprise trial cannot be upgraded to a non-evaluation installation legally.

Comment: :( tnx you should make that an A, if you dont wanna bother it is ok. :)

Comment: btw will it copy my existing HDD content to Windows.Old ? I remember I think Win7 being nice and doing that on install where previous installation was detected :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the tool [UpDown8](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/36726-UpDown8-Windows-8-Upgrade-Downgrade-Helper), to change some registry values. When you now run the Setup.exe from a running Windows and select ["Upgrade" (repair Install/Inplace Upgrade)](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html) the Enterprise Eval is downgraded to the Edition you want.

[image]

Comment: does it really do anything? I'm still not getting any options but "clean install" after switching to Win 8 Pro.

Comment: do you run the setup.exe from the running Eval version?

Comment: I've tried setup from the original eval version and 8.1 pro disk. They both don't show any upgrade options.

Comment: maybe it is broken now with 8.1, but it worked in 8.0.

Comment: it seems it works if I set windows edition to "core" and run win 8 pro (not eval) installer.

Comment: you always have to use the proper ISO not the Eval DVD. Normal ISOs include the Core and Pro Edition.